# Page event is not getting fired at all

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use the `Page_LoadComplete` in my user control `myusercontrol.ascx.cs` but its not getting fired up, I added a break point and nothing, it is possible that the user control does not support this event? and if thats the case what can I use instead?

Comment: How have you used this event because I thought only the Page had the event available... also from microsoft: "The LoadComplete event occurs after all postback data and view-state data is loaded into the page and after the OnLoad method has been called for all controls on the page."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `LoadComplete` event only happens on the `Page`.  For a control, if you want to do something after the other controls' `Load` events have fired, about the closest you'll get is `PreRender`.

Alternatively, you could attach to the Page's `LoadComplete` event in your control's init stuff.  But AFAIK it won't happen automatically.

Answer (score 26):

LoadComplete is not automatically wired up.. You'll have to do that yourself.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(Page_LoadComplete);
    }

    void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do your deed
    }
```

Reference: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/103322/page-loadcomplete-doesnt-fire-in-custom-controls